# Library issue change selected tab color

Tags: android, tabs

I am using this [library](https://github.com/savvyapps/ToggleButtonLayout)

```
implementation 'com.github.savvyapps:ToggleButtonLayout:1.0.0'
```

I am facing problem in the library it cannot allow me to change selected tab color.

I don't find any solution for change selected tab color in the library please help me.

and please help me to change the unselected tab color

my requirement is to show selected color white and unselected color green how to implement this please help me

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: This is difficult to answer the question 'as-is'. Please, add some relevant code and error log.

Comment: I mean library has its own fix color and there is not any helping material that gives me some support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is option available  to change selected tab color Using **`app:selectedColor="@color/colorPrimary"`**

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<com.savvyapps.togglebuttonlayout.ToggleButtonLayout
    android:id="@+id/toggle_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:allowDeselection="false"
    app:customLayout="@layout/view_toggle_button"
    app:dividerColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
    app:selectedColor="@color/colorPrimary" // provide your color here
    app:menu="@menu/toggles"
    app:multipleSelection="true"
    app:toggleMode="even" />
```

Comment: I want selected color white and unselected color green how to implement this

Comment: @MiteshMakwana did you any solution.. I want change textcolor on toggle selection is it possible?